# How to read from and write to multiple subfolders?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop

Under the /mypath/orc/ path I have several subfolders for different dates:
ie

```
/mypath/orc/mydate=20170817/part1.orc
/mypath/orc/mydate=20170817/part2.orc
/mypath/orc/mydate=20170820/part1.orc
/mypath/orc/mydate=20170820/part2.orc
/mypath/orc/mydate=20170821/part1.orc
/mypath/orc/mydate=20170821/part2.orc
```

My desired output is similar to this (the actual name of the file is not important):

```
/mypath/parquet/mydate=20170817/part1and2together.parquet
/mypath/parquet/mydate=20170820/part1and2together.parquet
/mypath/parquet/mydate=20170821/part1and2together.parquet
```

I have been trying the below and I could hardcode the filter on each date and call this 3 times but it will run for a long time if I have 1000s of dates. What am I missing in the code to make it process multiple date inputs into multiple date outputs in one go?

```
./spark-shell 
val orcfile = "hdfs:///mypath/orc/*/*.orc*"
val df = spark.read.format("orc").load(orcfile) 
df.createOrReplaceTempView("MYTBL") 
val results = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM MYTBL")
results.write.mode("Overwrite").format("parquet").save("hdfs:///mypath/parquet/")
```

Env:

1. Spark 2.3.0 in standalone mode
2. Hadoop 2.8.3
3. EC2 cluster - 1 Master with 64 CPU, 256GB RAM and 5 workers (each with with 64 CPU, 256GB RAM)

Long time is "days to weeks", would ideally like it to run in less than a day.

Comment: What exactly is "a long time"?  Seconds? Minutes? Hours? Can you tell us about your cluster? How many workers? Is it an in-memory or distributed cluster?  We need more context here.

Comment: A few thousand dates taking weeks to process doesn't seem right if the issue is Spark itself.  I suggest you do some profiling with a few dozen dates in local mode to see where if one can identify the bottleneck there.

Comment: All up around 800,000 dates to process, I know over that many iterations the spinning up of new JVM's for each call will be significant

Comment: Try to see if you can checkpointing your data reduces the spent time. I found that my spark jobs used to get stuck but checkpointing solved that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess partitionBy("myDate") ala:

http://javaagile.blogspot.com/2017/12/parquet-vs-avro-vs-orc.html

Whereas, partitioning so:

```
spark.read
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .csv("IN_FILE").sort(partitionBy)
    .write.partitionBy("STREET").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .parquet("OUT_PARTITIONED")
```

produces a directory structure like:

```
$ hadoop fs -ls OUT_PARTITIONED.parquet | head
Found 69415 items
drwxrwxr-x   - user user          0 2017-11-23 09:16 OUT_PARTITIONED.parquet/STREET=%22%22%22Glück-auf%22%22-Straße%22
drwxrwxr-x   - user user          0 2017-11-23 09:16 OUT_PARTITIONED.parquet/STREET=%22Kellergasse %22%22Moorberg%22%22%22
drwxrwxr-x   - user user          0 2017-11-23 09:16 OUT_PARTITIONED.parquet/STREET=0Montangebiet
drwxrwxr-x   - user user          0 2017-11-23 09:16 OUT_PARTITIONED.parquet/STREET=0Tallage
```

where in this particular instance, I had street data. Note that since I partitioned on `STREET`, each street now has its own directory.

This can be handy when you want to join within a partition but be careful you don't create too many entries in the Hadoop NameNode.

You get a similar difference if you use Orc, that is: